# Meteor FullCalendar dayClick conversion event

Tags: javascript, meteor, fullcalendar

I am using meteor and fullcalendar. I am trying to use the dayClick:function in my template but it is not working.

I would like the dayClick to fire when I click on the day without the use of jQuery. I understand that the way the Template.....events is setup that it will not work. I clearly do not understand some(many)thing(s).

Template:

JS

```
Template.calendar2.helpers({
calendarOptions: {
    // Standard fullcalendar options
    height: 700,
    hiddenDays: [],
    slotDuration: '01:00:00',
    minTime: '08:00:00',
    maxTime: '19:00:00',
    lang: 'en',
    // Function providing events reactive computation for fullcalendar plugin
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        //console.log(date);
        //console.log(start);
        //console.log(end);
        //console.log(timezone);
        var events = [];
        // Get only events from one document of the Calendars collection
        // events is a field of the Calendars collection document
        var calendar = CalEvents.findOne(
            { "_id":"myCalendarId" },
            { "fields": { 'events': 1 } }
        );
        // events need to be an array of subDocuments:
        // each event field named as fullcalendar Event Object property is automatically used by fullcalendar
        if (calendar && calendar.events) {
            calendar.events.forEach(function (event) {
                eventDetails = {};
                for(key in event)
                    eventDetails[key] = event[key];
                events.push(eventDetails);
            });
        }
        callback(events);
    },
    // Optional: id of the calendar
    id: "calendar1",
    // Optional: Additional classes to apply to the calendar
    addedClasses: "col-md-8",
    // Optional: Additional functions to apply after each reactive events computation
    autoruns: [
        function () {
            console.log("user defined autorun function executed!");
        }
    ]
},
});
```

Here is the event

```
Template.calendar2.events({
    dayClick:function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
            CalEvents.insert({title:'New Event',start:date,end:date});
            Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
    }
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I didnt have a clear enough understanding of how full calendar works. I did not need to a click event to initiate an date/event. fullcalendar already has a way to do that with dayClick: function(); I just needed to place within calendaroptions{};

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        CalEvents2.insert({title:'NEW', start:date._d, end:date._d});
        Session.set('clickedDate', tempEvent);
        IonModal.open('_cal2Modal');
    },
```